# My Navigation Won't Work with Anchors?

Tags: html, css, scroll, navigation, horizontal-scrolling

My Website: emilyjane.ca

My navigation will not jump to the sections properly in my horizontal scrolling site, and I can not figure out what is wrong. Each section has one large div with all it's containing elements inside. I have linked my navigation with an a href "#" and linked that to ID's in my html to create anchors. The Print navigation menu link is specifically not moving to the correct place at all. Please help!

**CSS & HTML**

```css
#printsection {
    width: 3700px;
    height: 530px;
    float: left;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
     position: relative;

}

#title {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left:0px;
}


#page2silk {
 width: 300px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:200px;
    position:absolute;
    /*width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    position:absolute;*/

    
}


.silk {
    float:left;
  width:600px;
    margin: 0px 0px 600px 150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="nav">
           <ul>
            <li> <a href="#printsection">PRINT</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#websection">DIGITAL</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#illustrations">ILLUSTRATION</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#photography"> PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
            <li  class="letstalk"> <a href="#letstalk"> LETS TALK</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#https://www.instagram.com/emilyjane.design/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li> 
         
            </ul>



    </div>
        
        
        <div id="printsection">
        <section id="title" > 
          
 <h4>
   <span> PR</span>
   <span> INT </span>
  </h4>
        </section> 
            
    <section id="page2silk" > 
            
        <h3> 
        Branding + Packaging 
         </h3>
        
        <h1> 
        Silk Rebrand 
        </h1>
        
        <h2> 
        A rebrand of the packaging and identity for Silk Almond Milk. It is packaged in a frosted glass bottle, which is eco-friendly by being 100% recyclable. The brand is stongly type based, using the typeface Acumin Pro. 
        </h2>
        <section>       
     <img src="a3_ilse_website/Desktop_A3-assets/silk.png" alt="silk" class="silk"/> </section>
</section>
          </div>
```

Comment: The nav is going to the sections, it just might not seem that way depending on the direction you're moving. If you're going forward it goes to the beginning of the target (which I'm guessing is what you're looking for), but if you go backward, it goes to the "end" of the target element which in your case shows part of the other sections and cuts off the title of the current section

Comment: Yes I want it to always go to the beginning of the target no matter what order you go in, how can I do this?

Comment: Because of the way anchors work, the most consistent way would probably be to use javascript/jquery and get the exact positions of where you want it moved too